# LG Ultrawide 21:9, MBP 2017 no HiDIPI 2560x1080

Tags: macos

I have a LG Ultrawide 34WN650 and a 2017 MacbookPro(Big Sur) with both Radeon Pro 560 4 GB
and Intel HD Graphics 630 1536 MB. I have purchased a USB-C to Displayport  cable, a USB-C to HDMI cable, QuickRes and SwitchResX.

Do you know how to get HiDIPI 2560x1080 resolution? QuickRes has a HiDIPI 1280 X 540 that does nothing when I click it. 1280 X 540 looks excellent but it is 16:9 not 21:9. I can't use custom resoultions in SwitchResX because they are "Not installed" after save and restart. The video and pictures are excellent in normal 2560x1080, but the fonts are extremely bad.

I have tried:

- https://medium.com/@nvucuong/macos-blurry-texts-on-an-external-full-hd-monitor-d2a955c25607
- https://www.chanhvuong.com/4403/fix-blurry-text-on-mac-using-external-non-apple-monitor/
- sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist DisplayResolutionEnabled -bool true)

Comment: That LG isn't a HiDPI screen, it's an ultrawide "HD" screen.

Comment: It doesn't need to be, it can run HiDPI resolutions, please see that through QuickRes 1280 X 540 looks excellent but it is 16:9 not 21:9

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Stephan Madrau, the creator of SwitchResX I have found a solution for my problem:

- half of the non HiDPI resolution is the HiDPI resolution, so I am using SCALED 3840 x 1620 non HiDPI --> 1920 x 810 HiDPI. It is a bit big.. but it is looking fresh and crisp.

Comment: https://ibb.co/Sd3TWBY